# Reading data in one cell and writing to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel file and I want to read each value within a cell... i.e A cell in column B row 2 may contain ("1 - 10 - 11 - 15 - 17") or  ("1-10-11-15-17") with or without the spaces between the hyphen. I want to read each number and save each value as the number 1 in another column on the same row. For example my column B row 2 data is ("1 - 10 - 11 - 15 - 17") or  ("1-10-11-15-17") and I want to write a value of 1 on the same row 2 in columns C, L, M, Q, and S as the value of 1. How can I read the data from a cell and write in another cell using a Macro or VBA?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Rose

---

EDIT:

This is just an ex of code

```
Sub Macro1() 
RowCount = Worksheets("2013").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
For i = 2 To RowCount cellvalue = Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "B").Value 
    If InStr(cellvalue, "1") = 1 Or InStr(cellvalue, "1") > 2 And InStr(cellvalue, "1") < 22 Then 
        Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "C") = Null 
    ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "10") <> 0 Then Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "L") = 1 
    ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "11") <> 0 Then 
        Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "M") = 1 
    ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "12") <> 0 Then 
        Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "N") = 1 
    Else Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "C") = Null 
    End If
```

Comment: B2 is ("1 - 10 - 11 - 15 - 17") or ("1-10-11-15-17").
 C2 is 1 for 1.
 L2 is 1 for 10.
 M2 is 1 for 11.
 Q2 is 1 for 15.
 S2 is 1 for 17.

Comment: What specifically would you like to see in the cells you are assigning new values to?  Should C2 be "1:1"?  "1-1"?  "1 for 1"?  Also, is there any code you have tried?  If so, what errors have you gotten?

Comment: This is just an ex of codeSub Macro1()
RowCount = Worksheets("2013").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount
cellvalue = Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "B").Value

If InStr(cellvalue, "1") = 1 Or InStr(cellvalue, "1") > 2 And InStr(cellvalue, "1") < 22 Then
    Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "C") = Null
ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "10") <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "L") = 1
ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "11") <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "M") = 1
ElseIf InStr(cellvalue, "12") <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "N") = 1
Else
   Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "C") = Null
End If

Comment: The problem is I need the string to be recognized as numbers so that it will not confuse the number 1 and the number 15 or 14 or 19 as a 1 1 with a value of what position it is in the string. heres another cell of data in b2 ("11 - 14 - 16 - 18 - 19") it doesnt recognize that 11 as 11 it thinks that once it sees a 1 then a 1 goes in column C row 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

This should do what you want.

```
For i = 2 To RowCount
    cellString = Cells(i, 2).Value
    cellString = Replace(cellString, " ", "") 'This finds and removes any spaces from your string
    numbers = Split(cellString, "-") 'Splits remaining values into array delimited by the dash character

    Cells(i, numbers(1)).Value = 1 'Now the column is the number stored in the array
    Cells(i, numbers(2)).Value = 1 'The array starts at index 2 because of the above For loop
    Cells(i, numbers(3)).Value = 1
    Cells(i, numbers(4)).Value = 1
    Cells(i, numbers(5)).Value = 1

Next i
```

Comment: Check the edit, should now do what you're looking for.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't reading through my own code very well. After you made that change, does it now work? If so, please accept the answer or if not, please explain what is not working.

Comment: Comments remove formatting. Edit your question and you'll be able to display table-style data.

Comment: I tweeked your code Thunderblaster and was able to complete my project, thanks for your help!

Comment: RowCount = Worksheets("2013").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount
cellvalue = Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "B").Value
cellString = cellvalue
cellString = Replace(cellString, " ", "") 'This finds and removes any spaces from your string
numbers = Split(cellString, "-") 'Splits remaining values into array delimited by the dash character
A = (numbers(0))
B = (numbers(1))
C = (numbers(2))
D = (numbers(3))
E = (numbers(4))
'This is not the complete code

Comment: For X = C1 To AO1
    If A = X Or B = X Or C = X Or D = X Or E = X Then
      If X = Worksheets("2013").Range("C1").Value Then
         Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "C").Value = 1
      End If
      If X = Worksheets("2013").Range("D1").Value Then
         Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "D").Value = 1
      End If
      If X = Worksheets("2013").Range("E1").Value Then
         Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "E").Value = 1
      End If
      If X = Worksheets("2013").Range("F1").Value Then
         Worksheets("2013").Cells(i, "F").Value = 1
      End If
   End If
Next x